# Error in implementing Firebase admin sdk in android studio

Tags: android, firebase, dependencies

When I am implementing firebase admin libraries 
it is showing error I have mentioned after my app and project level gradle files below.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    configurations {
        all*.exclude module: 'support-v4' // This removes all other versions of `support-v4` if gets duplicated from all the artifacts.
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.trolificnss"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {

    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.12.2'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.2.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.2.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.4.1"
    implementation "com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.0"
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-firestore:6.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.2.0'
    implementation 'net.schmizz:sshj:0.10.0'
}

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {


    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Below is the error message,

> In project 'app' a resolved Google Play services library dependency
>   depends on another at an exact version (e.g. "[1.21.   0]", but isn't
>   being resolved to that version. Behavior exhibited by the library will
>   be unknown.

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.21'
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.solamour.myserver"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath false
            }
        }
        resConfigs "auto"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    // Conflict with dependency 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305' in project ':app'.
    // Resolved versions for app (1.3.9) and test app (2.0.1) differ.
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.force 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'    // Or "1.3.9".
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'

    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:4.1.6'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
}




take a look at the javadoc for FirebaseOptions Builder in the Android client library:

com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.Builder

Now look at the same class from the java Admin SDK (note the URL is different):

com.google.firebase.FirebaseOptions.Builder
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove this:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.12.2'
```

You can't effectvely use the Firebase Admin SDK in an Android app.  It's meant only for code that runs on backend servers and desktop machines.

Also, you should always make sure your Android client library dependencies are at the current versions shown in the [release notes](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android).  Your Firebase-UI library versions should also match with the other Firebase libraries.

Comment: So, what should I use to call other user's emails?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking.  If you need to use the Admin SDK for something, you should do that from a backend that the client can invoke.

Comment: How can I do that will you please help me out?